# Solution to ETXTBSY errors when running npm in VirtualBox shared folder

Tags: node.js, npm, virtualbox, file-permissions

This is a known issue for a long time, but I can't find any definitive solution.

Basically if a module is installed with `npm install module`, and that module creates symlinks or installs other modules that create a symlink, the installation will fail with an error. Usually `ETXTBSY` or `ENOENT`.

This happens on Windows host that is running a Ubuntu virtual machine, and the folder in which the modules are installed is a shared folder that belongs to the host.

Adding the `--no-bin-link` argument helps sometimes but it doesn't work with all modules. The global option `-g` avoids the issue too but who wants to install every module globally?

Is anyone aware of a proper solution to this issue? It's really annoying because it makes programming in nodejs and on a Windows computer and testing in Linux impossible.